# Is there ready component in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*I want to get ready table component in react- native but is

it possbile or  I should create ?. I mean you know there are a lot of ready component in c# or android, but In react-native there is or not  ?*

Comment: go through with https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is ready components in react-native. Just google for React Native Table Component, and probably the first link will be this [React-Native-table-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out http://native.directory/ for a **curated list** of React Native components or search https://www.npmjs.com/ for **react native table**